# Получить данные из `$_SERVER` без спецсимволов

Tags: php

В адресной строке: `/computerzubehör-/`, но через `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` получаем `/computerzubeh%C3%B6r-/`. Как получить строку как есть, без замены спецсимволами?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
urldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```